# How to Group Rows together in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I need to group the same ID into one row and keep the row containing the most data.

If an ID group have no data, I still want 1 row returned. I have roughly 30 data columns.

Example:

| ID | City | Country | Data A | Data B | Data30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 | Country1 | DataA1 | DataB1 | DataN1 |
| 1 | City2 | Country2 | Null | Null | Null |
| 1 | City3 | Country3 | Null | Null | Null |
| 2 | City1 | Country1 | DataA1 | DataB1 | DataN1 |
| 2 | City2 | Country2 | Null | Null | Null |
| 2 | City3 | Country3 | Null | Null | Null |
| 3 | City1 | Country1 | Null | Null | Null |
| 3 | City2 | Country2 | Null | Null | Null |
| 3 | City3 | Country3 | Null | Null | Null |

Result:

| ID | City | Country | Data A | Data B | Data30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 | Country1 | DataA1 | DataB1 | DataN1 |
| 2 | City1 | Country1 | DataA1 | DataB1 | DataN1 |
| 3 | City1 | Country1 | Null | Null | Null |

Any suggestion would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do if you sum the number of non-null columns and then apply a `row_number`

```
with cte as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by id order by tot desc) rn
        from (
        select * , Iif(data1 is null,0,1) + Iif(data2 is null,0,1) + Iif(data30 is null,0,1) tot
        from t
    )x
)
select id, city, country, data1, data2, data30
from cte
where rn=1
```

See [Working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/993f4/1)

Comment: Instead of listing 30 columns, is there an easier way to write this part?
" Iif(data1 is null,0,1) + Iif(data2 is null,0,1) + Iif(data30 is null,0,1)"
I would be counting all columns for non-null